# Полнотекстовый поиск MySQL - поиск по первой букве

Tags: mysql, полнотекстовый-поиск

Использую такой запрос

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE 'Б%'
```

Но можно ли использовать fulltext для поиску по индексах, думаю это будет на много производительней

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас могут быть проблемы с поиском таких коротких фраз при помощи полнотекстового поиска, особенно на база данных содержащих небольшое количество записей.

Дело в том, что у полнотекстового поиска имеются ограничения алгоритма: он игнорирует слишком часто повторяющиеся фразы, например, вхождения результатов поиска в более чем половину записей (а вероятность вхождения одной буквы в половину записей довольно высока), в другой стороны поиск игнорирует ключевые слова короче определенного количества символов. По умолчанию это значение равно 4 (впрочем его можно отрегулировать директивой `ft_min_word_len` конфигурационного файла my.cnf).

По умолчанию полнотекстовый поиск не ищет слова по шаблону вроде 'Б%' или 'Б*' - он ищет слова целиком. Чтобы искать по шаблону, придется активировать логический режим полнотекстового поиска (BOOLEAN MODE)

```
SELECT * FROM articles MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+Б*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```