# Как сделать автодополнение через MySQL FULLTEXT index?

Tags: mysql, search, полнотекстовый-поиск

Есть таблица, например `tag`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаю поиск через `match against`. Вот запрос:

```
SELECT id, name FROM tag WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST (:search WITH QUERY EXPANSION)
```

Вот результат, если искать слово `chevrolet`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Вопрос:
Как сделать поиск не полностью по слову `chevrolet`, а только по части слова, например: `chevr`?

Если слово не написана полностью то `match against` не выдаёт результат. Есть что-то кроме LIKE?

Comment: Используйте BOOLEAN MODE, добавляя к текущей подстроке расширитель: `AGAINST (CONCAT(:search, '*') IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данный вопрос уже был на StackOverflow, [Полнотекстовый поиск MySQL - поиск по первой букве](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/471822/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-mysql-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B5)
Просто не поискал правильно. 
Решение такое:

```
SELECT id, name FROM tag WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('+chevr*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```